# Sorting a array. Help me to understand

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

im new in javaScript and i need to understand why my array is not sorting in alphabetic order.

Probably im missing something. Somebody can help me?

This is my TS

```
  getEmpresas() {

this.empresaService.getAll().subscribe({
  next: empresas => this.empresas = empresas,
  error: err => console.log(err),
});
let empresas = this.empresas.filter(obj => obj?.nome.toLowerCase());
empresas.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.nome < b.nome) { return -1; }
  if (a.nome > b.nome) { return 1; }
  return 0;

})
return empresas;
```

}

sry i paste a wrong one.

and here the class Empresa

```
  export class Empresa {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
  nomeCurto: string;
  inscricaoEstadual: string;
  inscricaoMunicipal: string;
  cnpj: string;
  telefone: string;
  email: string;
  caminhoLogoTipo: string;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#sort_an_array

Comment: Can you give an example of the array of empresas so we can have more info about your problem?

Comment: Can you please give the whole function that returns `sortEmpresa`

Comment: Instead of `.filter` before the sort use `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

A `subscription` is `asynchronous`. This means the line `this.empresas = empresas` will not be executed before your sorting function. Just put your sorting call inside the subscription, and don't bother returning a value. `this.emprasas` will be populated and sorted after receiving a response from your service.

Also, I believe you are trying to convert all names to lower case with `filter`. This is not what filter does, I've exchanged this line with a call to `map` that will convert all names to lower case.

```js
  getEmpresas() {
    this.empresaService.getAll().subscribe({
      next: (empresas) => {
        empresas = this.empresas.map((obj) => {
          return { ...obj, nome: obj?.nome.toLowerCase() };
        });
        empresas.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (a.nome < b.nome) return -1;
          if (a.nome > b.nome) return 1;
          return 0;
        });
        this.empresas = empresas;
      },
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
    });
  }
```

Comment: Nothing. He dont show the options. 
And thinking better now, i dont need toLowerCase, because the options come from a database, and he show all options when i click in the txt field.

I show the options but i cant reorder...

Is Somethink like this

[_____________] empresas  >click<
[__nonono__] 
[__nanana__]   [__ninini__]<-- this is the options to show in alphabetic order.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest I didn't understand a word of that, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
getEmpresas() {
    this.empresaService.getAll().subscribe({
      next: (empresas) => {
        empresas = this.empresas.map((obj) => {
          return { ...obj, nome: obj?.nome.toLowerCase() };
        });
        empresas.sort((a,b) => (a.nome > b.nome) ? 1 : ((b.nome > a.nome) ? -1 : 0))
        this.empresas = empresas;
      },
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
    });
  }
```